# How to restore Chrome "size-to-best-fit" zoom functionality?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome for Mac used to have the behavior that clicking the green "maximize" button would resize the window to best fit the page content. For example, if your Chrome window wasn't wide enough horizontally to fit the text of the webpage, clicking the green button would expand the window horizontally until it perfectly fit the text. It seems in recent versions of Chrome this was discontinued in favor of the green button full-screening the window.

I prefer the old behavior... I'm using Yosemite and short of reverting to an old version of Chrome, is there any way I could get it back?

Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to hold on option key and click the "green" button.